# To find the month corresponding to vnedor name and latest payment

Tags: excel

I am having a table for the payments made to different subcontractors and suppliers in different months and against different invoices. I want to get the month in a summary sheet for a particular vendor against the latest invoice. Can anyone give the idea how to get it please?

Comment: Did you try anything? Try pivot tables, share you problem, and also share sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

[image: Sample Worksheet]

First step would be to sort the data according to the vendor. I have sorted them according to column A.

Use advanced filter to get the unique values in column F to create your summary

in column **G** use the formula `=COUNTIF($A:$A,$F2)` to get the number of entries for each invoice.

in column **H** type the following formula:

`=MAX(INDIRECT("C"&ROW(INDEX($A$2:$A$18,MATCH($F2,$A$2:$A$18,0)))&":C"&ROW(INDEX($A$2:$A$18,MATCH($F2,$A$2:$A$18,0)))+SUM(G2)))`

The formula works as follows:

1. Sets the range for `MAX` using `INDIRECT`
2. Uses `INDEX` and `ROW` inside the `INDIRECT` formula to find the first row in the range `$A$2:$A$18` that corresponds to the vendor name as a starting point for the `MAX` formula.
3. Using the count of the invoice entries in column **G** you set
   the end of `MAX` formula range.

When you evaluate the formula in cell H2, the end result should be `=MAX($C2:$C5)` and this is returned to you as a result.

This works because dates are stored as numbers in excel. If there is more than one invoice from the same vendor in the same date it will still work.

To show the month, you could format the cell as `MMMM YYYY` or nest the formula inside a text formula if the desired output is just a text, something like:

`=TEXT(MAX(INDIRECT("C"&ROW(INDEX($A$2:$A$18,MATCH($F2,$A$2:$A$18,0)))&":C"&ROW(INDEX($A$2:$A$18,MATCH($F2,$A$2:$A$18,0)))+SUM(G2))),"MMMM YYYY")`

Implementing it in your workbook should be easy, as long as you sort the entire table based on the Vendor name.

I hope this helps.